# Power BI - Difference between Slider and Hierarchy filter

Tags: powerbi

I made a report with two pages with same calculated measure in a card visualization.
One page with slider filter and other page with Hierarchy filter. The value shown in the card is different in both the pages

FYI - slider filter gives out the correct value.

This is the sample formula I am using for the measure

```
RIF = CALCULATE(DIVIDE((SUM(SafetyIAR[Injury Count ]) * 200000), SUM('Hrs Worked'[Hrs]), 0))
```

Comment: You should check the  hierarchy, because if you select the third element is like selecting the first and second element also.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all your response. I fixed this issue I had. My report is working fine now. I used "calculate" to find the RIF.